# How to Scan string in c#

Tags: c#, string, model-view-controller, replace, find

this is my string .how to change it

for example:

F:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Setup Cash Desk\cash desk.exe

change it to

"F:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Setup Cash Desk\cash desk.exe"

Comment: Do you mean adding quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = @"F:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Setup Cash Desk\cash desk.exe";

s= "\"" + s + "\"";
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MbkOJ9)

Answer (score 0):

add backslash(\) before all quotations in the string.